# Splas / First frame image not working in a flowplayer module

Tags: 7, files

I am using drupal.org/project/video and drupal.org/project/flowplayer module to display the flv videos from video module. Everything works fine, except the splash/first frame image. Video module successfully creates 5 thumbnails from a movie and i can display these thumbnails in a view, but when i load a node with player it showing not a generated thumbnal, but first frame from the movie.

How can i set generated thumbnail as a splash image with flowplayer?